# Creating a map function inside a map in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, map-function

I have a JSON array like below. I want to generate dynamic components using the array. I have an array inside the array and need to generate a checkbox dynamically inside a card.

```
export const DemoProductSpec =
{
    "productSpecCharacteristic": [
        {
            "configurable": false,
            "name": "testing",
            "productSpecCharacteristicValue": [
                {
                    "value": 2000
                },
                {
                    "value": 2002
                },
                {
                    "value": 2003
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "configurable": false,
            "name": "testing2",
            "productSpecCharacteristicValue": [
                {
                    "value": 20003
                },
                {
                    "value": 200233
                },
                {
                    "value": 200333
                },
                {
                    "value": 20034
                }
            ],
        },
    ]

}
```

My react code is as below. but this code is not working. first map function is working. but the second map is not working.

```
{DemoProductSpec.productSpecCharacteristic.map((Characteristic) => (
        <Card
            title={Characteristic.name}
            bordered={true}
            size="small"
            extra={
                <Radio.Group onChange={onChange} value={value}>
                    <Radio value={1}>Deafult</Radio>
                    <Radio value={2}>Overriden</Radio>
                </Radio.Group>
            }
        >
            {" "}
            <span>Values: </span>
            {Characteristic.productSpecCharacteristicValue.map((Values) => (<Checkbox>{Values.value}</Checkbox>))}
        </Card>
    ))
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error (if so please post it), is it just not rendering?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Some other details about what is not working?

Comment: The jsx you posted seems fine, does your Card component accept and render its children? Could you post the code for the Card component?